# Scala gui doesn't work

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface

I am trying to create a gui in scala but it has problems, although I added the dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-swing_2.11" % "1.0.1"
```

in the `build.sbt` file.

Here is a known simple code:

```
import scala.swing._

object FirstSwingApp extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "First Swing App"
    contents = new Button {
      text = "Click me"
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler asks for GraphicsConfiguration parameter for MainFrame - but I think it gets no parameter...

Comment: fyi, `SimpleGUIApplication` is deprecated since Scala 2.8, use `SimpleSwingApplication` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @edi points out, `SimpleGUIApplication` has been deprecated ages ago. In fact that trait *does not exist* any longer, as you can see in the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/scala-swing/#scala.swing.package).

So your code cannot possibly compile under Scala 2.11. Perhaps you are using an old Scala version? Then you should't try to link to a library (Swing module) compiled against Scala 2.11.

You can ensure that by using sbt's `%%` artifact operator:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "1.0.1"
```